Custom encryption / decryption on SqlAlchemy columns
I am using MS SQL and SQLAlchemy ORM, and I am storing BigInteger primary keys in all my tables.
I want a solution that will:

Encrypt the PKs when fetched
Decrypt the encrypted PKs when passed as bind-params to a query
Have an ability to also fetch the original PK (integer) based on specific workflows

I have tried using a custom TypeDecorator that will encrypt the PK in process_result_value and decrypt the PK in process_bind_param. This works, but I also want to be able to fetch the original column data (int) as part of the query.Using hybrid_property, I can decrypt the column on fetch, but this will only work when I have the entire model instance with me. Almost all my queries are column-selection-based.
def encrypt(data):
    ...

def decrypt(data):
    ...


class EncryptedPK(sa.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sa.BigInteger
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return decrypt(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return encrypt(value)


class TableA(DbEntity):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'

    table_a_id = sa.Column("table_a_id", EncryptedPK(), primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column("name", sa.String(200, "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"))

    @hybrid_property
    def table_a_id_o(self):
        return int(decrypt(self.table_a_id))

model = TableA({'name': self.name})
session.add(model)
session.flush()
pk_e = model.table_a_id
pk_o = model.table_a_id_o  # HERE I CAN GET THE ORIGINAL BACK USING THE HYBRID PROPERTY SINCE I HAVE THE CLASS INSTANCE

res = session.query(
    TableA.table_a_id.label('table_a_id'),
    TableA.name.label('table_a_name'),
    TableA.table_a_id_o.label('table_a_id_o')
).filter(
    TableA.table_a_id == self.table_a_id
).all()

This obviously does not work since I need to extend the hybrid_property with an expression. However, I am not sure if this would work since I will have to have the same encryption and decryption function in SQL Server. Also, I would assume the indexes would all get blown up and the performance would take a hit.
I could, however, decrypt after I get the results. However, this is a lot of code change for a big application. I am looking for a solution that would work in the query layer itself.

Asked and answered on GitHub here.
